# Data series error conversion to.monthly

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I am trying to analyze finance data of BOVESPA (BRAZIL STOCK EXCHANGE). My exchange data starts in 2004 and end in 2017.

When I did the conversion **`to.monthly`** my series become from 2006 to 2013. 
Why did that happen?

```
####install.packages("quantmod")
library(quantmod)
####install.packages("PerformanceAnalytics")
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
####install.packages("zoo")
library(zoo)

####Definindo diretório principal
setDefaults(getSymbols, src='google')

StartDate = as.Date("2004-01-01") ####data de começo
EndDate = as.Date("2017-01-01") ####data de término


ibovespa <- getSymbols('IBOV', from=StartDate, to=EndDate, auto.assign = F)
ibovespa_monthly <- to.monthly(ibovespa) #->->->->->->->->->problem#####
colnames(ibovespa_monthly) <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close","Volume")
ibovespa_return <- (Return.calculate(ibovespa_monthly$Close)[-1,])*100
plot.zoo(ibovespa_return, xlab="Mês", ylab = "Porcentagem")

table.CalendarReturns(ibovespa_return)
```

Comment: The problem was that "IBOV" data has incomplete data in some days. When I turn to.monthly, the incomplete data is used as cut point of the serie.

Comment: That is correctly! Thanks you!!!